# Replacing special characters in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement to replace '&' in one of the table column which is not encoded at the time of insert.

I tried it with below query,

```
select regexp_replace('hello & hai &amp; &quot; &apos;'
       ,'&[^((amp;)|(quot;)|(apos;))]','&amp;') as decodedval 
from dual;
```

It is converting non encoded '&' as expected, but removing space between '&' and 'hai'. Could any one please tell me what's wrong I am doing?.

Comment: Your expression means "replace & plus one more character that is not one of these". Do you need a regexp in the first place?

Comment: yes, it should not consider the next one. Regexp should replace only & and not any of the other special characters which are already encoded

Comment: You'd normally use a non-capturing group but I can't get the Oracle syntax right and post a proper answer. Alternatively, you could add the matched character to the replacement expression but (again) I'm not sure whether Oracle supports that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode everything and then re-encode the string:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/5229)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(
         DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(
           'hello & hai &amp; &quot; &apos;',
           1
         ),
         0
       ) AS decodeval
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/5229/0)**:

```
|                           DECODEVAL |
|-------------------------------------|
| hello &amp; hai &amp; &quot; &apos; |
```

**Query 2 - Update to keep surrounding tags**:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(
          REGEXP_REPLACE(
            DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(
              DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(
                '<tag>hello & hai &amp; &quot; &apos;</tag>',
                1
              ),
              0
            ),
            '^&lt;(.*?)&gt;',
            '<\1>'
          ),
          '&lt;(/.*?)&gt;$',
          '<\1>'
        ) AS decodeval
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/5229/1)**:

```
|                                      DECODEVAL |
|------------------------------------------------|
| <tag>hello &amp; hai &amp; &quot; &apos;</tag> |
```

Comment: @RaghavaCh If it has answered your question then you can accept the answer to mark the question as closed.

Comment: facing another issue with the above solution, actually we are keeping the entire column content in one of the xml tag. The above solution is converting tags '<' and '>' to their encoded values which we don't expect.

Comment: @RaghavaCh Updated to restore tags at the start and end of the string. [Any additional tags in the middle of the string will be encoded - and it assumes you haven't got any confusing attributes in the tag like `<tag attr=">">`]

Comment: Thanks, everything fine now!